# Помогите разобраться в решении алгоритма для разворота односвязанного списка

Tags: java, алгоритм, linked-list

Была задача на разворот односвязанного списка. Решить не смог, нашел готовое решение в гугле. Но сколько не сижу с и дебагером, и без, не как не пойму в целом как оно работает хотя занимает 7 строк всего.

Помогите пожалуйста объяснением словами как оно работает, а то совсем(((

```
public class ReversingLinkedList<T> {

    private Node head;

    @SafeVarargs
    public ReversingLinkedList(T... values) {

        Node previous = null; //previous node

        for (T value : values) {

            Node node = new Node();
            node.setValue(value);

            if (previous != null) {
                previous.setNext(node);
            } else {
                head = node;
            }
            previous = node;
        }
    }

    public ReversingLinkedList<T> reverse() {
        Node node = head;
        Node previous = null;

        while (node != null) {

            //Next item.
            Node tmp = node.getNext();

            //Swap items.
            node.setNext(previous);
            previous = node;
            head = node;

            //Next item.
            node = tmp;
        }

        return this;
    }


    private class Node {

        private Node next;

        private T value;

        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node next) {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public T getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фактически поддерживаем две цепочки.

Идем по первой. Текущий узел. Запоминаем в `tmp` следующий за ним, и добавляем текущий во вторую цепочку *первым*. Переходим к следующему (в `tmp`).

Так поочередно, начиная с первого узла (который во второй цепочке становится последним) идем и переносим по узлу в начало (что в односвязном списке делается очень просто).

Когда первая цепочка опустеет - следующего просто нет (`null`) - все узлы уже во второй цепочке.